# Is there added value in using Text::CSV for writing output?

Tags: perl, csv

If I am writing tabular output to a file as CSV, what advantage does loading an extra module
[`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)
and converting my data to an object get me over a basic loop and string manipulation? I have seen a couple of answers that suggest doing this: [*How can I get column names and row data in order with DBI in Perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2283266/1463788) and [*How do I create a CSV file using Perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444096/).

Loading up an entire module seems like overkill and significant overhead for something I can write in four lines of Perl (ignoring data retrieval, etc.):

```
my $rptText = join(',', map { qq/"$_"/ } @head) . "\n";

foreach my $person ( @$data ) {
    $rptText .= join(',', map { qq/"$person->{$_}"/ } @head) . "\n";
}
```

So what does loading
`Text::CSV`
get me over the above code?

Comment: `join(',', map { qq/"$person->{$_}"/ } @head)` is better as `join(',', map { qq/"$_"/ } @{$person}{@head})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For <strike>simple</strike> trivial data (which, admittedly, is quite common) there's no advantage. You can `join` , `print`, and go on your merry way. For a quick throw-away script that's likely all you need (and faster, too, if you'd need to consult the Text::CSV documentation).

The advantages start when your data is non-trivial.

- Does it contain commas?
- Does it contain double-quotes?
- Does it contain newlines?
- Does it contain non-ASCII characters?
- Is there a distinction between `undef` (no value) and `''` (empty string)?
- Might you need to use a different separator (or let the user specify it)?

For production code, the standard pro-module advice applies:

- Reuse instead of reinvent (particularly if you'll be generating more than one CSV file)
- It keeps your code cleaner (more consistent and with better separation of concerns)
- CPAN modules are often faster (better optimized), more robust (edge-case handling), and have a cleaner API than in-house solutions.
- The overhead of loading a module is almost certainly a non-issue.

Comment: Also, `Text::CSV` will, by default, use the XS  module `Text::CSV_XS` as its backend, which will be substantially faster than any non-trivial Perl equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Your CSV won't be valid if `$person->{col1}` contains `"`. Also, all columns will be wrapped in double quotes, which might not be desired (e.g. numbers). You'll also get `""` for undefined values, which might not work if you plan to load the CSV into a database that makes a distinction between `null` and `''`.